# Explanation of the constants used while calculating hashcode value of java.util.hash

Tags: java, hash

Can someone explain the significance of these constants and why they are chosen?

```
static int hash(int h) {
        // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
        // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
        // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
        h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
    }
```

source: java-se6 library

Comment: Not a duplicate, nor an answer, but you may find this interesting reading if you're looking into this stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538092/why-does-a-hashmap-rehash-the-hashcode-supplied-by-the-key-object

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding strange Java hash function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335169/understanding-strange-java-hash-function)

Comment: You are very unlikely to get an answer to this question on this site. The best people to ask would be the designers of the `HashMap` class: Doug Lea, Josh Bloch, Arthur van Hoff, and Neal Gafter. Although, if I had to guess I would say these numbers were determined empirically.

Comment: These were definitely chosen experimentally.

Answer (score 2):

Understanding what makes for a good hash function is tricky, as there are in fact a great many different functions that are used and for slightly different purposes.

Java's hash tables work as follows:

1. They ask the key object to produce its hash code. The implementation of the `hashCode()` method is likely to be of distinctly variable quality (in the worst case, returning a constant value!) and will definitely not be adapted to the particular hash table you're working with.
2. They then use the above function to mix the bits up a bit, so that information present in the high bits also gets moved down to the low bits. This is important because next …
3. They take the mod of the hash code (w.r.t. the number of hash table array entries) to get the index into the array of hash table chains. *There's a distinct possibility that the hash table array will have size equivalent to a power of 2, so the mixing down of the bits in step 2 is important to ensure that they don't just get thrown away.*
4. They then traverse the chain until they get to the entry with an equal key (according to the `equals()` method).

To complete the picture, the number of entries in the hash table array is non-constant; if the chains get too long the array gets replaced with a new larger array and everything gets rehashed. That's relatively fast and has good performance implications for normal use patterns (e.g., lots of `put()`s followed by lots of `get()`s).

The actual constants used are fairly arbitrary (and are probably chosen by experiment with some simple corpus including things like large numbers of `Integer` and `String` values) but their purpose is not: getting the information in the whole value spread to most of the low bits in the value ensures that such information as is present in the output of the `hashCode()` is used as well as possible.

(You wouldn't do this with perfect hashing or cryptographic hashing; despite the similar names, they have very different implementation strategies. The former requires knowledge of the key space so that collisions are avoided/reduced, and the latter needs information to be moved about in all directions, not just to the low bits.)

Answer (score 0):

I have also wondered about such "magic" numbers. As far as I know they *are* magic numbers.
It has been proven by extensive testing that odd and prime numbers have interesting priorities that could be used in hashing (avoid primary/secondary clustering etc).
I believe that most of the numbers come after research and testing that prove statistically to give good distributions. Why *specifically* these numbers do that, I have no idea but I have the impression (hopefully collegues here can correct me if I am way off) neither the implementers know why these *specific* numbers present these qualities